# B+ tree - what is the rule regarding non leaf pages?

Tags: database, indexing, tree, b-tree

Is it OK for a non leaf page in a B+ tree to hold a number which is not equal to none of the leaf pages?

Comment: B tree or B+ tree?

Comment: B+ tree (just edited the question)

Comment: B+ trees have all the indexed data on the leaves. I guess you can not do that but then you will confuse people if you still call that a B+ tree

Comment: Let's asuume root tree 15. to his left, there is a non leaf page with the number of 10. This non leaf page has 2 childs (leaf pages): [4,6] [11,12]. Is this situation possible? We can expect to replace the non leaf page from 10 to 11. However, can we hold it to 10 and it will remain a B+ tree? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the keys in the internal blocks may be different from the actual keys that are stored in the bottom (data) layer of the B+ tree.

These internal keys only serve to set intervals, not to represent the actual key. For instance, to *find* a key in the tree, the traversal will always be to the bottom layer of the tree, and only there it is identified (or determined it does not exist). The internal keys only serve to determine the direction of the search.

Like you suggest, this can reduce the update-work needed when a key is *deleted*. Unless this deletion triggers a merge, there is no need to go upwards in the tree and update keys.

The fact that keys in internal blocks do not need to correspond to actual data keys, is also used for *saving space*. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree#Implementation) mentions:

> For internal blocks, space saving can be achieved by either compressing keys or pointers. For string keys, space can be saved by using the following technique: Normally the <sup>th</sup> entry of an internal block contains the first key of block  + 1. Instead of storing the full key, we could store the shortest prefix of the first key of block  + 1 that is strictly greater (in lexicographic order) than last key of block .